# PlutusData construction using @emurgo cardano-serialization-lib-browser

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, datum, emurgo

I have a JSON format needed for PlutusData serialization (but the format is not a standard datum in a list). The datum is wrapped in `Maybe` monad, so you'll note the nested lists (an array inside the outermost `fields`).

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fields": [
        { "bytes": "581ccb9fba6103382ffac26484e35af190bc885510f6a25ee3dbdc673bea" }
      ],
      "constructor": 0
    }
  ],
  "constructor": 0
}
```

The inner bytes are CBOR hex of a sample pubkeyhash. We know that to construct the inner datum we'd do:

```
const datumPkh = PlutusData.from_bytes(pkhCBORBytes);
```

to insert that in a list is also trivial:

```
const innerList = PlutusList.new()
innerList.add(datumPkh)
```

However, since we cannot add a PlutusList to a PlutusList, would we convert the `innerList` to bytes and read those bytes into a PlutusDatum like:

```
const outerList = PlutusList.new()
outerList.add(PlutusData.from_bytes(innerList.to_bytes()))
```

Or, should we do something else like a ConstrData's value to_bytes() and then a PlutusList.from_bytes...etc.?

We know we can't tell if the end results are the same from the hashes of the data in cardano-cli and the serialization lib as noted in: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/333 and https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/247

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help,

[`typhonjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stricahq/typhonjs) supports creating plutusDataCbor using utility method

```
const plutusDataBuffer = typhonjs.utils.createPlutusDataCbor({
    constructor: 0,
    fields: [12, 12],
});

const plutusDataCBOR = plutusDataBuffer.toString('hex');
```

You can pass in whole JSON object to generate plutusData.

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the structure of:


{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fields": [ CBORBytesOfPkh ],
      "constructor": 0
    }
  ],
  "constructor": 0
}

Answer (score 1):

[Mehul](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users/117/mehul-prajapati) was correct. [@strictahq/typhonjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stricahq/typhonjs) does work correctly and produces the same result as

`cardano-cli transaction hash-script-data --script-data-file test.json`

Where test.json contents are:

```
{ "fields": [{ "fields": [{ "bytes": "cb9fba6103382ffac26484e35af190bc885510f6a25ee3dbdc673bea" }], "constructor": 0 }], "constructor": 0 }
```

and JS content

```
import { utils } from '@stricahq/typhonjs';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import { PlutusData, hash_plutus_data } from "@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser"
const pkh = Buffer.from(await getPubKeyHash());
const datum = utils.createPlutusDataCbor({
  fields: [{ fields: [pkh], constructor: 0 }],
  constructor: 0,
});
const plutusDatum = PlutusData.from_bytes(datum);
const datumHash = hash_plutus_data(data);
console.log(Buffer.from(datumHash.to_bytes()).toString('hex'))
```

We are still trying to determine if that pkh needs to be CBOR encoded first, but that is secondary now that the structure works and produces the same hashes.